# Make scrolling jump to the next image in a list (not be continuos)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make something similar to the effect below. When you scroll the scrolling isnt continuos, instead you jump to the next image down. 
http://www.yesstudio.co.uk/

I image its pretty complicated JS so im very open to other solutions that achieve a similar affect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use JS. Use JQuery. Shouldn't be that complicated.
If you look at the page source, you'll see that images are loaded normally in order. All you have to do is put one

```
<div style='width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;z-index:2'>
    <img id='pic' src=''>
</div>
```

into your html, and then update `src` atribute depending on `$(window).scrollTop()`. I think JQuery has a function that tells you which elements are visible. Not sure though. Look it up.

Give it some thought.